# Removing the shadow on button click

Tags: android

I have created a list of buttons in my app and I have set the background to be an oval shape. On press of each button, I see a shadow of rectangle shape, how do I remove the shadow.

Please check the screenshot below:

[image: Button shawdow]

Here is the button in XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/buttonLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/buttons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_compose"
        android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
        android:text="@string/ver"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@color/blacktext" />

</LinearLayout>
```

roundedbutton drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:endColor="@color/white"
        android:angle="270" />
    <corners android:radius="55dp" />
    <stroke android:width="5px" android:color="@color/buttoncolor" />
</shape>
```

Comment: use `<solid>` tag and give background color white.

Comment: Would you please try to use `Button` instead  `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton`.

Answer (score 0):

add this to the button style:

```
shadowOffset: { height: 0, width: 0 },
shadowOpacity: 0,
elevation:0
```

it should remove button shadow on android

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a selector to your background, like this

```
<item android:state_selected="true">
// if you want to change the color or any thing on press of the button, do that here
    <shape 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:endColor="@color/white"
            android:angle="270" />
        <corners android:radius="55dp" />
        <stroke android:width="5px" android:color="@color/buttoncolor" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item >
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:endColor="@color/white"
            android:angle="270" />
        <corners android:radius="55dp" />
        <stroke android:width="5px" android:color="@color/buttoncolor" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your button

```
android:stateListAnimator="@null"
```

But `android:stateListAnimator` is for api >= 21. If your **min sdk < 21** , You can use

```
style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
```